# best method for header Location in Laravel5.2 part of view files

Tags: php, header, laravel-5, soap-client

I use soap client PHP7 in `Laravel -> resources -> view` file for connect to Bank payment method, and my soap client is enable.

my code in view file is something like this:

```
if ($result->Status == 100) 
    header('Location: https://domain.com/Pay/'.$result->Authority);
else 
echo 'false';
```

but header not working !!! also i used from `redirect()` - `Redirect::to()` - `Redirect::away()` but not worked for me !!!!! (amazing)

what is best method for solved this my problem??

thank you guys

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Do you get an error? Note that you must send headers before ANY other output.

Comment: i had not any error ! just when is use it code the action page show me just white page, dont me error because i used else at the continue but it had not error it is true but dont work get to loaction

Comment: A white screen suggests an error that has been hidden. Check your server's error logs or turn on on-screen error reporting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: my error is on when i use only only return redirect('http://google.com'); in view file not work !!! but when use at it action working !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can found the my problem ! and i think it was amazing

i just added `die();` end of header loaction  for example :

```
if ($result->Status == 100) 
header('Location: https://domain.com/Pay/'.$result->Authority) or die();
```

and it worked for me !!!